A more general product rule for weak derivatives?
Consider that $u_1,u_2:\Omega\to (0,\infty)$ where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is an open set. We know that $u_1,u_2\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for some $p>1$ and $\dfrac{u_1}{u_2},\ \dfrac{u_2}{u_1}\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. How can we show that for any $1\leq r\leq p$ we have that:
$$
u_2\left (\dfrac{u_2}{u_1}\right )^{r-1}\ \text{and}\ u_1\left ( \dfrac{u_1}{u_2}\right )^{r-1}\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)\:?
$$
I found this statement as a straightforward remark in the following paper:
Peter Takáč, Jacques Giacomoni, "A $p(x)$-Laplacian extension of the Díaz-Saa inequality and some applications". (English)
Proceedings of the Royal Society of Edinburgh, Section A: Mathematics 150, No. 1, 205-232 (2020), MR4065080, Zbl 1436.35210.
Here it is a print screen from page 9 of the preprint version of that article



I know about the ACL (absolute continuity on lines) characterization of the function from $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and I also know about the product rule for weak derivatives (even a generalized version as this Math.SE Q&A, but in this situation we do not know that $u_1$ and $u_2\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

For $\varepsilon>0$ consider a continuous function $\theta_\varepsilon:\mathbf{R}_{>0}\rightarrow\mathbf{R}_{>0}$ equaling the identity map on $I_\varepsilon:=(\varepsilon,\varepsilon^{-1})$ and constant outside this interval. Define $u_{k,\varepsilon} := \theta_\varepsilon(u_k)$.
You can check directly that the functions $u_{k,\varepsilon}$ have Sobolev regularity with gradient given by $\mathbf{1}_{u_k\in I_\varepsilon}\nabla u_k$.
Also, since the ratios $u_1/u_2$ and $u_2/u_1$ are bounded, so are the ratios $u_{1,\varepsilon}/u_{2,\varepsilon}$ and $u_{2,\varepsilon}/u_{1,\varepsilon}$, and this is true independently of the parameter $\varepsilon$.
Now, for fixed $\varepsilon$ you may compute the formula just as you want by generalized chain-rule and then pass to the limit (in $\varepsilon$) to recover the expected gradient.
